# Proper way to stretch elements?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have: http://jsfiddle.net/walkerneo/JnEpS/3/

Assuming I want the following:

- Gray boxes change height on resize, but constant width
- Blue box changes height and width on resize
- Cyan box changes width but not height on resize

What is the proper way to do it?

The way in the jsfiddle is done by stretching the element by setting its position to absolute and making its left, right, top, and bottom to 0px. I'm loving how easy this is compared to using table display properties or lengthy code, but I get the feeling it's something that shouldn't be done.

Is this proper code? If not, what is?

Comment: This might break in older browsers, but it looks fine

Comment: You might want to read up on [The Holy Grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/) method for creating layouts. Might not necessarily help you in this scenario but will give you a general sense of how you should be formatting layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the "proper" way to do it. I can't think of any other way to go about it that doesn't involve tables that might not even work.